# SQL aggregate events to a count by timestamp

Tags: sql

Assuming you have tables like this:

```
---------------------------------
| created                       |
---------------------------------
| id | timestamp                |
---------------------------------
| 1  | 2021-11-17 08:26:36.203  |
| 2  | 2021-11-17 08:26:50.342  |
| 3  | 2021-11-19 09:00:00.000   |
---------------------------------

---------------------------------
| deleted
---------------------------------
| id | timestamp                |
---------------------------------
| 2  | 2021-11-18 07:21:34.342  |
| 1  | 2021-11-18 07:22:35.321  |
| 3  | 2021-11-19 09:00:00.000  |
| 4  | 2021-11-20 09:00:00.000  |
---------------------------------
```

This can be accumulated into one table like this:

```
SELECT timestamp, concat(CASE WHEN created.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'CREATED'
                              ELSE '' END,
                         CASE WHEN ended.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'DELETED'
                              ELSE '' END) as event
FROM created
  FULL JOIN  ended USING (timestamp)
order by timestamp
```

Which results in a table like this:

```
----------------------------------------
| timestamp                | event     |
----------------------------------------
| 2021-11-17 08:26:36.203  | CREATED   |
| 2021-11-17 08:26:50.342  | CREATED   |
| 2021-11-18 07:21:34.342  | DELETED   |
| 2021-11-18 07:22:35.321  | DELETED   |
| 2021-11-19 09:00:00.000  | CREATED   |
| 2021-11-19 09:00:00.000  | DELETED   |
| 2021-11-20 09:00:00.000  | DELETED   |
```

How would it possible to crate tables that count how many items exists on a certain time? Meaning we have CREATED events that mean an item gets created. Then then there are DELETED events that mean an item gets deleted. So in the table above we have an item created at timestamp '2021-11-17 08:26:36.203' another one at timestamp '2021-11-17 08:26:50.342'. So by that time the count of items is 2. At timestamp '2021-11-18 07:21:34.342' an item gets deleted so the count of items is again 1. Then at timestamp '2021-11-18 07:21:34.342' again an item gets deleted so the amount of items is 0.

Actually it can be noted that here I am not interested which item (identified by id) got created or deleted. Just the total amount of items at a specific time is interesting.

When items are created and deleted with the same timestamp there should be no entry (as the number of items did not change).

E.g the expected result would look like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
| timestamp                | number of items |
----------------------------------------------
| 2021-11-17 08:26:36.203  | 1               |
| 2021-11-17 08:26:50.342  | 2               |
| 2021-11-18 07:21:34.342  | 1               |
| 2021-11-18 07:21:34.342  | 0               |
| 2021-11-20 09:00:00.000  | -1              |
```

How can this be achieved with SQL? How serious are the limitations of aggregating something like this with SQL?

**Edge cases**

- CREATED and DELETED with same timestamp: -> count as 0 -> create no entry
- More DELETED than CREATED: accept negative number
- Multiple created with same timestamp should be added up. This means that for example 3 CREATED with the same timestamp should increase the number of items by +3 but only give one entry in the final result. (same for DELETED)

**DBMS**

Actually the intended use case is [Presto](https://prestodb.io/) [to query data in Kafka](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/kafka-tutorial.html).

Comment: How do you distinguish CREATED and DELETED in your expected results? Also, what is that 0?

Comment: CREATED means an item gets created DELETED that an item gets deleted, so if you have 2 CREATED events and 2 DELETED events it means in total you have 0 items.

Comment: Then as you phrased your question it is far from clear. Edit and explain better with more sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: @forpas is it more clear for you now? Please explain why you need more sample data.

Comment: More sample data cover edge cases. Like when there are duplicate timestamps, which exist in your sample data. If at the same time there is an item CREATED and an item DELETED which one will be first? Is there another column that denotes the order of the rows? Also, the way that you want to count may lead to negative values. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @forpas: added data for edge cases. Is the question now acceptable for you?

Comment: Is it possible to have duplicate time values within the same table, i.e. in created (2,'2021-11-17 08:26:50.342') and (3,'2021-11-17 08:26:50.342')

Comment: @Ahmed: I added this corner case as well, see my last edit.

Comment: Ok, I was working on it, I didn't saw the updated edits, by the way, what `DBMS` you are using?

Comment: @Ahmed: I added at the end of the question: Presto

Comment: `group by` timestamp, use `sum(case when 'CREATED' then +1 case when 'DELETED' then -1)`. I do not know if presto supports case in aggregates. SQL standard do support, I think.

Comment: @user14063792468 Then I would just get the final number, but I actually want the numbers per timestamp

Comment: That is what `group by` is for.

Comment: @user14063792468: Now I got what you mean, you where referring to window functions

Comment: No, I am not referring to window functions. I misread your expected output.

Comment: Given this post has -2 votes and 1 close vote: What can be done to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
with cte as ( 
select timest, 1 as stsVal from created
  union all
select timest, -1 as stsVal from deleted
 ),
  cte2 as
 (
 select T1.timest,T1.stsVal from
 cte T1 inner join 
   (select timest, sum(stsVal) from cte
    group by timest having sum(stsVal) <> 0) T2
 on T1.timest=T2.timest
 )
 select distinct timest,sum(stsVal) over (order by timest) as numberofitems from cte2
```

The first `cte` is to merge the two tables into one and set a value of 1 for created dates and a value of -1 for deleted dates. This value stored in `stsVal`.

For created and deleted with the same timestamp and same number of entries, the `sum(stsVal)` will be zero, so in `cte2` the sum of all `stsVal` for each timestamp is calculated excluding zero sums by `having sum(stsVal)<>0`.

Now, using `cte2` we can find the accumulative sum of `stsVal` for each timestamp.

See a demo from [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jDaNvT9HRz6UpYb3cZWjFa/2).

The demo is in `MySQL 8.0`, I couldn't find an online playground for `Presto`, if you know one kindly update me.

Answer (score -1):

The following using window functions seems to do the job:

```
SELECT timestamp, SUM(SUM(change)) over (order by timestamp) as total FROM
(
  SELECT 
    timestamp, 
    CASE WHEN created.id IS NOT NULL THEN +1 ELSE -1 END as change 
  FROM created FULL JOIN ended USING(timestamp) 
  ORDER BY timestamp
) GROUP BY timestamp
```

Comment: What about "CREATED and DELETED with same timestamp: -> count as 0 -> create no entry" Does it fit in this approach?

Comment: No you are right, this case is not covered correctly....